# Is it possible to call setter as a method?

Tags: python, getter-setter, setter

Given following class, I can modify `_x` using the setter/getter construct. But is it now possible to change `_x` by calling a method?

The reason I'm asking is just because it would later be very convenient to define something as a lambda using `lambda y: (c.x := y)` which works in 3.8, but in 3.7 we'd need something like `lambda y: c.x.some_method_maybe(y)`.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self,_x):
        print(_x)
        self._x = _x
c = C()
c.x = 999 # this works
c.x.some_method_maybe(999) # call setter of x explicitly?
```

Comment: `c.x` is 999, it has the attributes any integer does. Why do you need a *method* - what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just added the usecase - but that is not really relevant to the question as there are other ways to solve it. I'm just curious about the object `property()` creates.

Comment: Why you want to use walrus operator with lambda ??

Comment: You can use this hack: `c.__class__.mro()[0].__dict__['x'].fset(c, 999)`

Comment: @dejdej it seems to be the most concise solution (you have to use `:=` because the normal assignment `=` does not work in a lambda). Otherwise you'd have to define a named function first that creates a lot more visual clutter. Or do you have another solution in mind?

Comment: The property object is defined on the *class*, so you can access e.g. `C.x.__set__`. But using `:=` to assign in a lambda is exactly the sort of thing people hoped you *wouldn't* do (it's [*"Valid, but unlikely to be useful"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link. I'd argue in this case it is the most concise and readable way to do it, even if they couldn't imagine this case whan planning it! Otherwise it would be simpler to explicitly write a `C.set_x` method that could be used directly without the lambda detour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make the getter and setter normal methods then pack them into a property afterwards

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    def get_x(self): 
        "getter for property x, see `help(C.x)`"
        return self._x
    def set_x(self,_x):
        "setter for property x, see `help(C.x)`"
        print(_x)
        self._x = _x
    x = property(get_x,set_x, doc="""\
                documentation of property x here, 
                `help(C.x)` will print this""")
```

then you can use `c.set_x` as your callback and the property `c.x` still works as you expect.

But notice that the method was totally allowed to do `self._x = _x` because it was a function instead of a lambda so you could just do the same where you need a callback:

```
def modify(y): c.x = y
```

As long as you are ok defining your lambda on it's own line this is always a valid design pattern, to just declare a short function for your callbacks.

Alternatively if you love one liners and lambdas and hate readability you can use the `__set__` magic method of the property on the class itself if you don't want to expose the setter directly.

```
modify = lambda val: type(c).x.__set__(c, val)
```

where `type(c)` gets the class object, `.x` gives the property object directly, `.__set__` is the magic method called when you set the property of an instance, and you call it with the instance as the first argument as you'd expect calling methods on classes to work.